# How can I turn off the PWR LED on a Raspberry Pi 2 when startup is complete?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

Based on http://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/controlling-pwr-act-leds-raspberry-pi, I understand that the PWR LED on a Raspberry Pi 2 can be turned off from the command line with the following command:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness
```

I also understand that the following can be added to /boot/config.txt to disable the PWR LED immediately and permanently at startup:

```
# Disable the PWR LED.
dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=none
dtparam=pwr_led_activelow=off
```

What is the best/easiest way to keep the PWR LED on during the boot sequence, but to then turn it off once the boot sequence is complete?

I tried adding the following as /etc/init.d/lightsoff:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          lightsoff
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Disable PWR LED when startup is complete
### END INIT INFO

echo none | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led1/trigger
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness
```

I then ran:

```
chmod 0755 /etc/init.d/lightsoff
```

Unfortunately, the PWR LED comes on at startup and stays on. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check, if your script is executed at all? I had a similar issue. In my case, systemd didn't care for my init.d script.. Doing it via a systemd script fixed it for me.